# .vscode/settings.json is empty but plugins are disabled in workspace

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to disable several plugins in certain workspace in VS code. So I've started vs inside workspace, opened plugins tab and clicked arrow next to disable button and choose `Disable (workspace)`. And it works. Now when I open certain workspace I have disabled plugins which I've disabled before. But where does VS code store the information about disabled plugins in workspace? In my workspace where I've disabled plugin I have `.vscode/settings.json` but this file is empty (same result if I do: `File > preferences > settings` choose `Workspace` and click `Open Settings` (top right)). Re-enabling plugins in workspace also works as expected.